# only fetch @ManyToOne releationship but dont persist Parent Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have following Enitities:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

}


@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private Parent parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

}
```

Now, when i save the Child i want to save the ID of the Parent into the Column "PARENT_ID".
But i don't want to save or update the Parent when the Child is saved.
Therefore i have added `updatable = false, insertable = false` to the @JoinColumn.
The Problem is, this way i get "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing".
So Hibernate tells me to save the Parent before the Child. Well, the Parent is already saved, but Hibernate doesn't know that because its a new Transaction and i don't want
to save the Parent again(thats the whole point of `updatable = false, insertable = false`). I also dont want to fetch the Parent again(no additional select, and i only need the ID(which i already have) not the whole object)

I already tried to annotate the getParent with @Transient to prevent persisting of the Parent, which works great, but when the Child is fetched, the Parent is not.
(i saved the ID with another Property which i set manually)

Is there a way how i can achieve what i want?
(fetching the Parent when i fetch the child, save the ParentID when i save the Child, but dont save or update the Parent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, it seems, is that you're creating a new Parent, although all you want is to attach a new child to an existing parent. Don't do that. Since the parent already exists, get it from the EntityManager:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
}
```

and, to save a new Child with an existing parent ID:

```
Parent existingParent = entityManager.getReference(Parent.class, parentId);
Child child = new Child();
child.setParent(existingParent);
entityManager.persist(child);
```

Comment: two stupid questions:
1. Best way to get the entitiyManger from a Spring @Component? (@Autowire?)
2. Does this work, even if the Parent was saved in another transaction and the Child is created in a new one?

Comment: 1. `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;` (but I assume you already have that, since you already try saving the child). 2. yes, of course. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Sadly i don't have that already. Saving is done via repositories (spring.data.repository). But i do have a entityManagerFactory defined in the servlet.xml, so i guess i will give it a try. :-)

Comment: You should definitely continue using the repository: `Parent existingParent = parentRepository.getOne(parentId)`. And the `getOne()` method will use the underlying EntityManager.getReference() method. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-

Comment: i accepted your answer although i had to use a different "solution". Despite looking like i have no clue what im doing(maby thats true nevertheless) i am working with a horrible codebase and the actual situation is far more complex than my simple example. Because of this, i couldnt get your solution to work, but i do think it would be the right one, it just doesnt fit into my codebase xD

Answer (score -1):

as commented on JB Nizet Answer, i had to use a different Solution, but i think you should use his, if you can.

My solution looks like the following:
- removing @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn from getParent() and annotating it with @Transient
- adding another Property (Long parentId)
- annotating parentId with @Column("PARENT_ID")
- when the Child is loaded from the DB, i get the parentId and load the Parent and add it to the child via its Settermethod